# Progress bar em angulajs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5, css3, progress-bar

Preciso de uma `progress-bar` que seja a imagem de um cálice sendo enchido com `AngularJs`. Algo parecido com isso: http://franverona.com/loadgo/.

Alguém te algum exemplo possa me ajudar?

Ainda não tenho a imagem oficial, mas seria algo mais ou menos assim: Ao abrir uma página, o líquido do cálice (`imagem 01`) subiria até completar todo o cálice (`imagem 02`)

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tem algum código, a imagem do cálice, em qual local do código é para acontecer isso?

Comment: O código te serviu Edinho?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse plugin não tem pra [angular](/questions/tagged/angular), tem que utilizar [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) ou **não** (acho mais simples com `jQuery`).

***Exemplo minimo***

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {    
    $scope.load = function() {
      $("#myImage").load(function() {
        $('#myImage').loadgo({
          'opacity': 0.5,
          'animated': true/*
          'image': 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uk8G.png'*/,
          'direction': 'bt'          
        });
      }).each(function() {
        if (this.complete) $(this).load();
      });
    };
    $scope.go = function() {
      var _time = window.setInterval(function() {
        if ($('#myImage').loadgo('getprogress') == 100) {
          $('#myImage').loadgo('setprogress', 0);
          $("#btnExecutar").text('Executar');
          $("#btnExecutar").prop('disabled', false);
          window.clearInterval(_time);
        } else {
          var i = ($('#myImage').loadgo('getprogress') + 4);
          $('#myImage').loadgo('setprogress', i);
          $("#btnExecutar").text('Executando ...');
          $("#btnExecutar").prop('disabled', true);
        }
      }, 150);
    };
    $scope.load();
    //$scope.go(); // remover para funciona no inicio do carregamento
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/LoadGo/2.1/loadgo.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" style="width:100%">  
 <p style="margin-botton:150px; float:left">
  <img id="myImage" style="width:300px" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sLfb.png" border="0" />
  </p>
  <button id="btnExecutar" ng-click="go()">Executar</button>
</div>
```

Nesse exemplo foi utilizado um botão, mas, no final do `script` tem um comentário é só descomentar (`//$scope.go();`) que isso funcionará no carregamento da página. As imagens também me parecem diferentes n

***Referencia:*** [LoadGo](https://github.com/netdragoon/loadgo)