# Imagem que vai "Preenchendo"

Tags: jquery, html, css, css3

Tem como eu colocar uma imagem e colocar um filtro para ficar preto e branco, e conforme eu quiser a imagem vai ficando colorida?

Exemplo: Tenho uma imagem de um item que quero conquistar, ele tem etapas para serem cumpridas. No inicio ela fica toda em preto e branco, e a cada etapa cumprida, eu queria que a imagem fosse ficando colorida. Tipo tem 3% de etapas concluídas, então o desenho fica 3% colorido e o resto preto e branco. Não sei se me expressei bem.

Comment: Você fala isso: https://github.com/netdragoon/loadgo e um resposta minha aqui apesar de não ser colorido tem a opção de colorir: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180926/54880, exemplos: http://franverona.com/loadgo/

Comment: Ae Virgilio, é isso mesmo! Não sabia nem como procurar...mas valews! Eu vou dar uma olhada! Obrigado!